# Populate a HTML table with csv data

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-4, html-table

Searching on internet i tried to copy and modify a jquery script to populate a HTML table with a csv data but it does not work: the table stays empty. Below i paste the code. Please advise why this does not work. I installed IIS on my PC to test this code locally.

The HTML page consists of 3 tabs and i am trying to populate the table on the first tab.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>test csvToTable</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Zelf toegevoegd-->
    <style>
        .project-tab {
            padding: 10%;
            margin-top: -8%;
        }
        .project-tab #tabs{
            background: #007b5e;
            color: #eee;
        }
        .project-tab #tabs h6.section-title{
            color: #eee;
        }
        .project-tab #tabs .nav-tabs .nav-item.show .nav-link, .nav-tabs .nav-link.active {
            color: #0062cc;
            background-color: transparent;
            border-color: transparent transparent #f3f3f3;
            border-bottom: 3px solid !important;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .project-tab .nav-link {
            border: 1px solid transparent;
            border-top-left-radius: .25rem;
            border-top-right-radius: .25rem;
            color: #0062cc;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: 600;
        }
        .project-tab .nav-link:hover {
            border: none;
        }
        .project-tab thead{
            background: #f3f3f3;
            color: #333;
        }
        .project-tab a{
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #333;
            font-weight: 600;
        }
    </style>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <section id="tabs" class="project-tab">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <nav>
                        <div class="nav nav-tabs nav-fill" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
                            <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Project Tab 1</a>
                            <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Project Tab 2</a>
                            <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false">Project Tab 3</a>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                    <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
                        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-contact-tab">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/PapaParse/4.1.2/papaparse.js"></script>
    <script id="rendered-js">
        function arrayToTable(tableData) {
        var table = $('<table class="table" cellspacing="0"></table>');
        $(tableData).each(function (i, rowData) {
        var table = $('<table class="table" cellspacing="0"></table>')
            if (i=0) {
                var thead = $('<thead></thead>');
                var row = $('<tr class="rownum-' + [i] + '"></tr>');
                $(rowData).each(function (j, cellData) {
                row.append($('<td class="' + [i] + '">' + cellData + '</td>'))});
                thead.append(row);
                table.append(thead);
                }
                else {
                    var tbody = $('<tbody id="tEuro"></tbody>');
                    var row = $('<tr class="rownum-' + [i] + '"></tr>');
                    $(rowData).each(function (j, cellData) {
                    row.append($('<td class="' + [i] + '">' + cellData + '</td>'))});
                    tbody.append(row);
                };
                table.append(tbody);
            });
        return table;
        }
        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost/NV_EuroData.csv",
        success: function (data) {
            $("#nav-home").append(arrayToTable(Papa.parse(data).data));
        } });
        //# sourceURL=pen.js
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi , can you show output of `tableData` ?

Comment: How do you do that? sorry i just have a very very basic knowledge of jQuery ..

Comment: just do `console.log(tableData)` inside your fn and you will see result inside your browser console.

Comment: For the first time i open the console and i find:

Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function
    <anonymous> pen.js:107
Test_csv.html:107:11
    <anonymous> pen.js:107

Comment: Hi because you are using `slim` version of jquery .Instead can you include this `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` and try again ? see what error you get after that.

Comment: Now it is working! thanks a lot @Swati.

Answer (score 0):

On your page, there is an ajax:

```
        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost/NV_EuroData.csv",
        success: function (data) {
            $("#nav-home").append(arrayToTable(Papa.parse(data).data));
        } });
```

this ajax load the file `NV_EuroData.csv` from your `localhost` server. It seems that the mentioned file can not be reached.

so, check whether that file is reached or not, by putting in your browser address bar

```
http://localhost/NV_EuroData.csv
```

so if you put that file in the right place, you will display it, so your page would work well.

looking forward to your comments.

***Based on your comment***

Try to rewrite the file name in both HTML and in the folder in small case letters like `nv_eurodata.csv`. and check `http://localhost/nv_eurodata.csv` and check the working of the HTML page.

Comment: Indeed, i got "HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found", i put the file just in the same folder as the html file (C:\inetpub\wwwroot). What could be the reason why NV_EuroData.csv is not reachable?